# How can I get the numbers above and below a MAX value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say I've got a column of 50 numbers and I know how to find the maximum with the Large function. How would one find the numbers that are directly above and below the said number?

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

I've attached a photo for reference. How would I create a function that would first find the largest number (500) and in the other cells find the value above (67,64,48) and below (71,75,88) it. Also, just to mention that the values in the column changes.

Comment: Do you mean relative location above and below?

Comment: I don't think so. I'll try to explain it in a little more detail. So all I want is the 3 numbers that are above and below the largest number in a column. The numbers constantly change so the relative location wouldn't output the numbers I'm looking for as they'd be static, is that right? Thanks again!

Comment: Can you edit your question with an example of data and expected result?

Comment: And how exactly do you want to output these numbers? In a single cell?

Comment: I've added a screen shot above.

Comment: I think you mean the two numbers located one row above and one row below the maximum value.  You can easily do this with [OFFSET (reference, rows, cols](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-offset-function). Use LARGE() or MAX() to specify the reference, 1 (or -1) for the rows, 0 for the cols.  Then, even if the numbers change, you'll always get the number one row up (or down) from the maximum number in the column.

Comment: Just saw your screenshot. You can also get the cells 2 or 3 or n rows above and below the Max. OFFSET() is your huckleberry. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. Uber noob here. What's wrong with this formula?=offset(LARGE(J1:J200)-1,0)

Comment: I got it working. Thanks again. =OFFSET(INDEX(J1:J100,MATCH(MAX(J1:J100),J1:J100,FALSE)),-1,0)

Answer (score 0):

*You can solve this issue in three steps.*

[image]

1. Use either the Max or Large function to find the highest value.

`=Max(A2:A28)` or `Large(A2:A28,1)`

2. In the cell above that formula (B15), put this formula and fill it
   up:

`=INDEX($A$2:$A28,MATCH(B16,$A$2:$A$28,0)+1,1)`

3. In the cell below that formula (B17), put this formula and fill it
   down:

`=INDEX($A$2:$A28,MATCH(B16,$A$2:$A$28,0)-1,1)`

**Note:** B16 is the cell with the formula for the largest value.
This approach will still return the correct values when the location of the largest value changes.